# How do I setup a php script to work with 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to coding, and trying to make a script to run as a cron.  Overall, I need a specific type of user from one table to find the ID's in the second.  This is for an accounting task on a larger website script, so changing anything with how the table isn't an option.

User table columns are as follows
id -- username -- password -- email -- deleted

Deleted is either 0 or 1 and the column we will be searching for.

transaction table columns are as follows
id -- time -- owner -- banker -- type -- amount -- reason

So i need to pull each unique user who has not been deleted (a 0) and go through all their transactions (owner) and add them all up (amount).  Perform some math on the result, and then create a new transaction for that user.

This is what I've got so far, doing a bit of hack job from some code within the webscript as well.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database"); 

$uniqeMembers = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users WHERE deleted='0'");

while ($id = $uniqueMembers->fetchRow())
    {
    $playerCreds = $playerCreds = getCol("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE owner='$id' LIMIT 1");
    $interest = $playerCreds * .05;
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO transactions (time, owner, banker, type, amount, reason) VALUES ($TIMEMARK, $id, 14, 0, $interest, 'Interest')");
    }


mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Right now, the code doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Any help?  Or a simpler method?

Comment: You have an error in the script first of all: $playerCreds = $playerCreds =... Remove one $playerCreds

Comment: $playerCreds = $playerCreds should only be listed once.  I messed up a copy/paste :L

Comment: Also where is getCol defined?

Comment: I thought that is how you select the column for doing the math.

Comment: No. See my edited code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easiest to do it as a single insert, using the selects as the source of data for the inserts. Something like this (not tested)

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "database"); 

$uniqeMembers = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO transactions (time, owner, banker, type, amount, reason) 
                SELECT '$TIMEMARK', users.id, 14, 0, (SUM(transactions.amount)) *0.05, 'Interest'
                FROM users 
                INNER JOIN transactions
                ON users.id = transactions.owner
                WHERE users.deleted='0'
                GROUP BY users.id");

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code, but I fixed it this way:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "animals"); 
if(!$con){
    die("Error");
}
$uniqeMembers = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users WHERE deleted='0'");

while ($id = $uniqeMembers->fetch_row())    {
    $transaction = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM transactions WHERE owner='".$id[0]."' ");
    $playerCreds = mysqli_fetch_array($transaction);
    $interest = $playerCreds[0] * .05;
    //mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO transactions (time, owner, banker, type, amount, reason) VALUES ($TIMEMARK, $id, 14, 0, $interest, 'Interest')");
    }


mysqli_close($con);
```